# Cordova/Ionic Facebook getLoginStatus not working

Tags: ios, cordova, facebook-graph-api, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I am developing an App in Ionic/Cordova with Login over Facebook. Before showing the "Login-Page" I would like to check if the user is already connected.

The following *getLoginStatus* check works as expected in the iOS Simulator. When testing on the actual device, the *getLoginStatus* callback does not get fired.

```
facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(
    function (response) { 
        if (response.status == "connected") {
            set_tokens(response);
            $location.path('/tab/person/me/events');
        }
    }, 
    function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) }
);
```

Already set the Facebook-App to public and verified the App-Id.

Can anybody give a reason for the described behaviour?

Comment: Are there some errors happening? The code seems valid but for example the `facebookConnectPlugin` might be undefined at that point for multiple reasons such as not waiting for deviceReady or not even including the plugin on actual packaged app.

Comment: There are no errors and the `facebookConnectPlugin` is defined. The code is called after `$ionicPlatform.ready()`.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following implementation for Facebook login using facebookConnect Plugin.

```
facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(
            function(response){

                if(response.status == "connected"){
                    //do something, for example share or redirect
                }else{
                    facebookConnectPlugin.login(["basic_info"],
                         function(success) { /*do something...*/},
                         function(error) {
                                  //handle error
                                });
                }
            }, function(error) { 
                       // handle error
            })

    }
```

If you still have errors, try to log the error and success events to see what is happening. This implementations works in a controller.